# Can player characters pick monster feats?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, monsters, character-templates

Some of my player characters have a race from a template but without monster hit dice (like half-orc) and others have a race from a template with monster hit dice (like ogre). Now in the back of Monster Manual I there are some monster feats, like [Awesome Blow](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsterFeats.htm#awesomeBlow). It says these are available to monsters so I guess the half-orc character cannot select these, but what about the ogre character? It does have monster hit dice after all.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## The *Monster Manual* feats aren't limited to monsters

A feat can be taken by any creature that qualifies for the feat based on the feat's type (for example, the most common type of feat is general, but the *Player's Handbook* also includes the feat types item creation and metamagic) *and* that meets the feat's prerequisites *and* that fulfills any conditions explained in the feat's description, benefit, special, or note (if any).

So, while the *Monster Manual* feats *are* "typically used only by monsters" (*MM* 303), if a PC meets the requirements for taking such feats, nothing technically prevents the PC from taking feats from the *Monster Manual*.

### The DM can always say *No*

If the DM—for whatever reason—doesn't *want* a feat in the campaign, the DM can make a house rule saying that feat is excluded from the campaign. As an aside, while it's usually easier to say, "No feats from this book," it's often better to ask a player's plan for his character instead then assess feat choices individually. Usually, a particular book has a mix of strong and weak feats, and banning a book means eliminating both reasonable and unreasonable choices.

Comment: Exactly this, keep in mind that feats such as "Awesome Blow" are incredibly easy for a DM to counter because of their high requirements.

Comment: Yes, most "monster" feats have prerequisites that a normal player character would not be able to meet. It's worth remembering however that a character who doesn't innately have a particular ability but can reliably attain it can take a feat which depends on that ability. For instance, a Druid who can use Wild Shape to become a creature with claw attacks could take Improved Natural Weapon (Claw), it just only applies when they are in the appropriate form. Or a fighter with Wings of Flying could take Flyby Attack. If you can do it reliably enough to practice it, you can take the feats.

Comment: @Carcer Can you cite a source for that? While that's a deeply reasonable house rule (and I don't use the term disparagingly), I am pretty sure a creature *must* meet a feat's prerequisites upon being *able* to take a feat *to* take a feat. That is, even if a creature *can* gain temporary abilities that enable the creature to meet a feat's prerequisites, if the creature doesn't meet the prerequisites when the feat would've been taken, the creature can't take it.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I wish I could but I've tried to search it now and realising I might have been conflating different things. [This question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60089/can-a-character-meet-prerequisites-using-a-magic-item) has some relevance. However I think I was specifically thinking about Pathfinder, where the Fly skill states: "You cannot take this skill without a natural means of flight or gliding. Creatures can also take ranks in Fly if they possess a reliable means of flying every day (either through a spell or other magical manner, such as a druid’s wild shape ability)."

Comment: @Carcer It's cool. An example of how complicated it can be to take feats for which the creature only *temporarily* meets the prerequisites is detailed in my answer [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/63292/8610) if you're interested.