# Can you send an enemy flying by dealing damage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e

I seem to remember a "build" for D&D 3 or 3.5 that if you damaged an opponent, they would have to make a Strength check vs the amount of damage done or be sent flying in 5 or 10 foot increments, and if their travel was hindered by someone or an object, the character and the object would take 1d6 damage for each range increment impeded, and if the object broke due to damage, the enemy would continue flying until the increments...

I'm trying to remember this was primarily for "large" or larger creatures... But my google fu is has failed me...

It might be from a 3pp that I'm remembering, but I don't think so... Any leads and help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Awesome Blow, which is indeed the first thing that came to mind for me in this question, it may be worth mentioning the Knockback feat in *Races of Stone*.

Knockback allows you to make a bull rush as a free action after hitting someone with Power Attack active. “Unlike standard bull rush attempts, [...] you don’t move with the enemy you knock backward,” so it’s very much a “send an enemy flying” kind of thing.

The advantage over Awesome Blow is that Knockback is a bull rush, which means everything that benefits from or keys off of bull rushes also work with Knockback. **That** is significant primarily because of the dungeoncrasher fighter in *Dungeonscape*, which can do **large** amounts of damage by bull rushing someone into a wall. A goliath barbarian/dungeoncrasher with Power Attack, Improved Bull Rush, and Knockback is a simple, effective build that can perform some battlefield control, and do a hefty amount of damage while doing it. War hulk (*Miniatures Handbook*) provides an absurdly potent—though costly—growth opportunity from there.

Comment: The Hulking Hurler is something I strive to avoid, as awe inspiring as it may be lol Very good catch with the Knockback feat from Races of Stone! I'll make sure to keep that in mind when making suggestions!

Comment: @AOKost Hulking hurler (*Complete Warrior*) is distinct from war hulk (*Miniatures Handbook*). The “awe” you’re referring to, though, may be the “war hulking hurler,” a prominent optimization build that combines the two (and many other Strength boosts besides) to abuse the hulking hurler’s uncapped damage that scales by the weight of the object thrown.

Comment: That's exactly what I was referring to, though I wasn't trying to confuse anyone... I'm just used to the term "Hulking Hurler" to refer to that prestige class combination.

Comment: @AOKost Sure, but separately the prestige classes aren’t terribly worrisome.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a dunce. After posting, I wrote a description to a friend, suggesting to call it "Mighty Blow" and that reminded me of a monster feat, that lead me to the answer:

There is a way, but it's a "monster feat" called Awesome Blow.

Comment: [PCs can take feats from the *Monster Manual.*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/82788/8610) They may have difficulty meeting the prerequisite, but they can if they do.