# When does the Endure Sunlight feat's benefit reset?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, undead, vision-and-light, duration

Let's say a vampire with the Endure Sunlight feat is fighting another vampire without that feat, and has a way of creating sunlight that can be turned on/off easily. (In the situation that came up in-game, it's a magic sword that can be made to shed sunlight.)

If the vampire turns on sunlight briefly and then turns it off, does the number of rounds he can endure more sunlight reset?

Answer (score 3):

There's no limit to the number of times a creature can benefit from the feat **Endure Sunlight** (*Libris Mortis* 26). The creature that possesses the feat need only not be exposed to sunlight to reset the feat's benefit. There's no per-day limit on the feat's benefit's use nor is there a minimum sunless time required for the feat's benefit to reset.

Thus it seems that a vampire can stand out in the sunlight for *almost* its maximum number of rounds then take a move action to get under a very large umbrella and, on that same turn, complete that move action by reentering the sunlight to work on his tan.

Comment: Or ditch the feat and become a vampire lord.... ^^

Comment: @nijineko Man, you can't just go around droppin' those bombs. Here's the template [vampire lord](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/mm/20021018a), dear readers. It, in part, says, "A vampire lord… can go about in broad daylight if it desires" but still suffers some penalties. However, if the DM doesn't permit the vampire to acquire it (as it does, after all, have an unlisted LA, and it says that lords "have lived as a vampire for at least 100 years, and have acquired 10 or more class levels or Hit Dice") then [a ninja costume'll work.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/106896/8610)